# Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser() always nil after upgrade to iOS14.5 (AWS Amplify iOS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amplify-ios

I am using aws Amplify-iOS to develop iOS app, and get a problem after upgrapded to iOS14.5

Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser()  always be nil after upgrade to iOS14.5   (AWS Amplify iOS)

Same source code that runing on iOS14.4.2 is just fine.

macOS Big Sur11.3 + Xcode12.5 + iOS14.5 + Swift version 5.4

Any idears please.

Thx

Comment: Did you get any resolution?
Amplify.Auth.signIn = success but mplify.Auth.getCurrentUser()  = null

"authenticationFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH"